# Synchronize one specific webservice call

Tags: java, multithreading, webservice-client

I'm wondering what the best approach to this problem would be. I have an (abstractly speaking) simple method that calls a webservice and stores the result in a local in-memory cache, something like:

```
public Document callWebservice(SomeObject parameter) { 
    Document result = cache.get(parameter);
    if (result == null) {
        result = parse(retrieve(parameter));
        cache.put(result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now, if the Document is in the cache, it can just return without problems, fine. In a singlethreaded environment, this approach works fine too. However, in a multithreaded environment, it turns out that each thread will turn to the 'else' bit, and call the webservice several times.

I could chuck a synchronized block in the 'else' part, but I believe that's too 'wide' of a lock - the whole method will be unavailable for calling threads even though they call completely different things.

It's fine if the webservice is called twice, as long as the request is different (i.e. the SomeObject parameter, in this case).

Now, question: What's the best approach to take in this case?

I've thought of storing the parameter in a (threadsafe) collection object. If the parameter's contents are the same, it'll produce the same hashCode / equals outcome and will be found in the collection object, indicating that another thread is already processing this request. If that would be the case, the calling thread could be paused until the webservice returns. (I'd have to figure out how to make the calling thread wait though). Would this work with a lock on the `SomeObject` parameter object? e.g:

```
private Map<SomeObject, SomeObject> currentlyProcessingItems = new ConcurrentHashMap<SomeObject, SomeObject>();
public Document callWebservice(SomeObject parameter) {
    if (currentlyProcessedItems.contains(parameter)) {
        parameter = currentlyProcessedItems.get(parameter);
    } else {
        currentlyProcessedItems.putIfAbsent(parameter);
    }
    synchronized(parameter) {
        Document result = cache.get(parameter);
        if (result == null) {
            Document result = parse(retrieve(parameter));
            cache.put(result);
        }
        currentlyProcessedItems.remove(parameter);
        return result;
    }
}
```

(note: logic for keeping track of the currently processing requests, usage of ConcurrentHashMap and the locking may be suboptimal or outright wrong)

No, I never actually finished reading the book on threading. I should.

I'm pretty sure this particular problem is quite common, I just wasn't able to find the answer. What is a situation like this called (i.e. locking on a specific object), if I may ask?

Comment: You got the equals and hashCode right on SomeObject?

Comment: Yes, the parameter has a good `hasCode()` and `equals()` method, based on Commons Lang's HashCodeBuilder and EqualsBuilder. Internally it has some objects too, which also properly implement `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking of the problem myself, especially when retrieve(parameter) takes a long time (For me, it is connect to a server to check authentication, process/filter request at back end, etc.). Now I have not tried this out myself yet, but for the the sake of discussion, how does this sound?

To use the cache, one has to call new MyCache(key).getValue() from a thread, since getValue will be locked in the method getCacheValue() until this value becomes available (to all waiting threads).

```
public class MyCache {

    private final static HashMap cacheMap = new HashMap();  // One Map for all
    private final static Vector fetchList = new Vector();   // One List for all

    private Object cacheValue;
    private boolean waitingState;

    public MyCache (Object key) {
        if (cacheMap.containsKey (key)) {       // somebody has done it
            cacheValue = cacheMap.get (key);
        } else {
            waitingState = true;
            if (fetchInProgress (key, false))   // someone else is doing it
                return;
            new Thread (new MyFetch (key)).start();
    }}

    synchronized private static boolean fetchInProgress (Object key, boolean remove) {
        if (remove) {
            fetchList.remove (key);
        } else {
            boolean fetchingNow = fetchList.contains (key);
            if (fetchingNow)
                return true;
            fetchList.addElement (key);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Object getValue () {
        if (waitingState)
            getCacheValue (true);
        return cacheValue;
    }

    synchronized private void getCacheValue (boolean waitOnLock) {
        if (waitOnLock) {
            while (waitingState) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException intex) {
        }}} else {
            waitingState = false;
            notifyAll();
    }}

    public class MyFetch implements Runnable {
        private Object fetchKey;
        public MyFetch (Object key) {
            fetchKey = key;     // run() needs to know what to fetch
        }

        public void run () {        // Grab the resource, handle exception, etc.
            Object fetchedValue = null; 
            // so it compiles, need to replace by callWebService (fetchKey);
            cacheMap.put (fetchKey, fetchedValue);  // Save for future use
            fetchInProgress (fetchKey, true);   // Remove from list
            getCacheValue (false);          // Notify waiting threads
}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Warning, the xml DOM objects are *not* thread-safe.  so (ignoring from the thread-safety issues of the cache itself) you cannot share a Document instance among multiple threads.  we got bit by this in our own code base, so i know for a fact that this is problematic (not just some theoretical problem).

as for the caching itself, i believe guava has what you are looking for: [a computing map](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html#makeComputingMap%28com.google.common.base.Function%29)

Comment: +1 on the warning, and another +1 for pointing me to ComputingMap, which looks just like the thing I'd be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Java 5 and upwards have classes which help doing exactly this.  You might find ConcurrentHashMap interesting:    http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_concurrency_8_hashmap.shtml

Answer (score 0):

I've given my own idea a go, and it actually seems to be working fine - first, it uses a `ConcurrentHashMap` (although a good concurrent Set would be better, haven't found a proper implementation yet) to maintain a list of object currently being processed.

In the method itself, it looks up if the map already contains an instance of the identifier. If it doesn't, it attempts to insert the identifier using `putIfAbsent()`. If between the check and the insert another thread inserts it, then the putIfAbsent method returns the other thread's inserted item and that one is used.

Then, with either the new identifier or the existing one, a synchronized block starts, locking on the identifier instance. In the synchronized block, the cache is consulted, and if that doesn't return results, the webservice is called. In effect, this means that all processes doing the same request (identified by the identifier) can only process one of those requests at the same time, so when the first one is calling the webservice, the other ones wait in line. When it's their turn, the result is in the cache, and the waiting threads can retrieve it from there.

As for the Document object not being threadsafe, I'm not sure what to do about that just yet. On my local machine it doesn't seem to cause any problems, but things like that have a habit of appearing in production at random. Grr. Will have to figure that one out, I guess.